# LDAP lookup using ODP.NET, Managed Driver Beta (Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll) fails in C# application

Tags: c#, oracle, ldap, odp.net, data-access

I'm using [ODP.NET, Managed Driver Beta](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) (Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll) in my C# application to access an Oracle database. This is to replace using the native version of ODP.NET in order to remove all the local dependencies on Oracle Client 10g/11g/etc. so that this needn't have to be installed locally. This is a solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13970965/197591).

This is my C# code:

```
new OracleConnection("Data Source=ABCDEFG1;User Id=myuserid;Password=mypassword;").Open();
```

This line is reached and the `OracleConnection` object is created successfully thereby suggesting all dependencies are loaded successfully. However, it throws an *OracleException* on the call to `Open()`. The error message is:

> Network Transport: Unable to resolve connect hostname

My organisation performs hostname lookups using LDAP and this is done via the ORA files using DIRECTORY_SERVER setting. However, I'm having difficulty getting it to do this using the managed version of ODP.NET. The ORA files are stored in C:\Apps\oracle\network\admin.

tnsping on my data source ('ABCDEFG1') works fine. So, I used the output of tnsping and added an entry for ABCDEFG1 in tnsnames.ora using this output. My application then connected successfully. So, I know that it is definitely finding and using the ORA files, but, for some reason, it won't perform the LDAP lookup that non-managed ODP.NET (in other applications) uses.

Is anyone who's used this new managed ODP.NET aware of this problem or what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked the same [question on the Oracle forums](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2491603), and someone there came up with an [answer](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=10817895#10817895). It appears that managed ODP.NET doesn’t support LDAP and this is in its [release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/odpmbetainstall-1696475.html).

I do have a [further question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566632) following on from this, though, and would be happy if anyone could help me further by answering that one instead.

Many thanks.

Comment: The following link suggests that ODP.NET Managed Driver does now support LDAP: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3516366